# How to sort array by child value of dynamic indexes?

Tags: php

How to sort this array by sort_order keeping in mind that initial two keys are dynamic, I tried with ksort but this didn't help me much.

```
    [3] => Array
            (
                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => text2
                        [id] => 3
                        [sort_order] => 2
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => text6
                        [id] => 4
                        [sort_order] => 6
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => text5
                        [id] => 2
                        [sort_order] => 5
                    )

            )
```

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: Could you add more details about your problem by providing the input, the actual and excepted output and what you did so far.

Comment: [3] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => text2
                    [id] => 3
                    [sort_order] => 2
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => text5
                    [id] => 2
                    [sort_order] => 5
                )

        )

     [3] => Array
        (

          [4] => Array
           (
             [name] => text6
             [id] => 4
             [sort_order] => 6
        )
)

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function

```
usort($array, function($item1, $item2) { return $item1['sort_order'] >= $item2['sort_order'];});
```

Comment: Undefined index: sort_order

Answer (score 0):

you have to flat your array then use the usort function

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $list) {
    $result = array_merge($result, $list);
}
usort($result, function($item1, $item2) { return $item1['sort_order'] >= $item2['sort_order'];});

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```